# Gnuplot yerrorlines xtics issue

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using Gnuplot with the 2,2 multiplot environment.

One of my datasets looks like this:

```
#   Avg1. Min1. Max1. Avg2. Min2. Max2. 
25  0.049 0.002 0.108 0.051 0.004 0.102
50  0.034 0.005 0.070 0.036 0.004 0.086
100 0.028 0.012 0.044 0.026 0.012 0.054
```

And I'm using the following script to plot the first graph (I think once I get the first one right I can just repeat the code):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set term post eps color solid enh
set multiplot layout 2,2 rowsfirst
set grid ytics
set offsets 0.5, 0.5
unset key
set ylabel offset 1,0
set xtics ("25" 1, "50" 2, "100" 3)

### First plot
set tmargin at screen 0.95
set bmargin at screen 0.65
set lmargin at screen 0.10
set rmargin at screen 0.45
set ylabel 'Y-Label Here'
plot 'data.dat' u :2:3:4 w yerrorlines ti 'Title1', \
     '' u :5:6:7 w yerrorlines ti 'Title2'

### three other graphs

unset multiplot
```

And I have three more plots like this. The problem is that my X-axis only shows 25 and 50 (shown below).
I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help please?
I've tried using 1:2:3:4 instead, but it shows the intermediate X-tics, which I don't want to show.

[PlotExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sh2l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify an explicit column for the x-value, then gnuplot uses the row index, which starts at zero:

```
set xtics ("25" 0, "50" 1, "100" 2)
plot 'data.dat' u 0:2:3:4 w yerrorlines ti 'Title1'
```

You can also directly use the values in the first column as xticlabels:

```
plot 'data.dat' u :2:3:4:xtic(1) w yerrorlines ti 'Title1'
```